# Get last index from list with where condition

Tags: java, android

How to get the last index from a array list with the where condition. I am a beginner in java. I have more swift experience, i used there this:

```
list.lastIndex(where: {$0.id == 1})
```

Comment: What you have done in other languages is not very helpful without knowing what you currently want to achieve in Java. Can you give an example of what result you expect with what input?

Comment: It want to get the last index in the list containing the given id.

Comment: Would something like [lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.Object)) help?

Comment: How about looping through the arraylist from back to front and break as soon as the condition is true.

Comment: In kotlin you have [findLast](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/find-last.html). In Java you probably need to iterate backward (you could extract that into a method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faster way is to loop from the end of the loop for example

```java
int index = -1;
for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (list.get(i) == 1) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

In Kotlin you can do like you did in Swift

```kotlin
val index = list.indexOfLast { it == 1 }
```

Another way in java is to use Stream and map every value to index with filter and get the max index after filter but it require all item to be unique so indexOf to not duplicate the keys

```java
Integer[] intArray = list.parallelStream()
        .filter(integer -> integer == 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(list::indexOf, (c) -> c))
        .values().toArray(new Integer[]{});
int length = intArray.length;
Integer lastIndex = intArray[length - 1];
```

I tested the speed of the 3 solutions and the result on my PC is

Solution 1: 11000     ns

Solution 2: 2388000   ns

Solution 3: 165954100 ns

So I think the best idea is to create a helper function that takes the list, function that validates the condition and returns the index using the first solution

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use lastIndexOf method
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-lastindexof-java-example/